What is the least positive integer value of N such that 7 + 30N is not a prime number?
I already know the answer by hit and trial, but have no idea how to approach and solve this question without inspection.

Why should there be a convenient answer?  Clearly $N=7$  gives you a composite, so it's just a matter of checking $1$ through $6$.

I was hoping there is a convenient answer as there is a second part to this question which goes like - Which is the smallest value of n, such that 30n+7 has at least three distinct prime factors? And its answer is not a small integer.

I'd say checking $6$ small values was pretty convenient...

Convenient in sense 'a general solution'.

@lulu Even $N=6$ works, since it is $187 = 11 \times 17$, but the rest of your comments stand.

@SarveshRavichandranIyer  Oh, I didn't mean to suggest that $7$ was minimal.  I'm just saying that that was a cheap way to bound the search.  Similarly, if you wanted the least $n$ such that $7+30n$ was divisible by a cube  you could solve $7+30n\equiv 0 \pmod  {7^3}$ to see that $n=217$ works for that, though that is not the least such $n$.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@lulu in your written solution to the divisible by cube problem, how do you get $7^3$ as the cube which should divide $30n +7$ , why not any number smaller.

I just guessed at it.  That was my point....algebraic methods let you give upper bounds but generally don't provide easy ways to solve the problem exactly.  $3,5$ are impossible so $7$ is the least possible guess.  As it happens, $13^3$ would have been a better guess, but I only found that one via a raw search.

Oh I see, so there appears to be no 'general way' of solving this question. Well anyways thank you for your time.

Since $7+30n$ needs to composite, the least value of $n$ can be either $7$ or less than it, since $7$ and $30$ are both co-prime numbers. Setting $n=7$ has $7+30\times7=7\times31$ here, so the number is surely composite.
To check for values of $n$ that is less than $7$, the numbers need to be within the range $1$ to $7$. Let the composite number be $k$, then, we have:
$$
7+30n=k$$
$$7=k+30n$$
Looking at the multiples of $30$, we find $180$ is the least number, that when added to $7$ generates a composite number, so the least value of $n$ is $180/6$ or $3$.

I think the OP wants to avoid "Looking at the multiples of $30$" part, which is what they probably meant by "a general solution" in the comments.
